# create table using exsiting table update/link to column

Tags: sql

I want to create a new table with one of the columns linked/updated by a table on another database (but on the same server). 
so when table A column is updated it will automatically update table b's column with the same information no data will be entered into this column from table b. 
I have tried various different ways but can't find a way to do this with out updating column manually or setting up a server agent any help would be great.

Comment: The basic method would be to create table B without the column in the second database, and then create a view which contains a query that joins tables A and B together.

Comment: You can create a trigger which updates table B when table A is updated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make cross server query, please check *sp_addlinkedserver*

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

Once it is linked, just create a trigger, where you can use

```
select * from [server].[database].[schema].[table]
```